# KeyError: 'use_threading' not letting me runserver

Tags: django

I'm new to coding in Python so bear with my errors. I keep encountering this error even when I haven't added anything into the code yet.

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[Name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\[Name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(self._args, self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[Name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[Name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 127, in inner_run
    threading = options["use_threading"]
KeyError: 'use_threading'
```

**Note:** I did migrations and makemigrations just in case but I still get the same error.